# Export Multiple Power Bi visual (Matrix and Table) to Excel

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerapps, power-automate

I am trying to export multiple pages in one report to excel (same spreadsheet) with the filters.

Is there any way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't export Power BI visuals to Excel for whatever reason. However, you can use *Analyze in Excel* to live connect to the Power BI dataset and then rebuild Power BI tables and matrices with Pivot tables. Note that this doesn't work with Power BI's implicit measures but explicit (DAX) measures only.